# Inserting multiple rows in a single record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have 4 columns, namely Call No., Acc. No., Title and No. of Copies. For each title, regardless of the number of copies, there is only one call no., however, the number of Acc. No. a book has depends on its no. of copies. So if there are 6 copies, there will be 6 Acc. Nos.

So I was wondering if it is possible in SQL to have multiple rows in a single record instead of having multiple records for each Acc. No.

Comment: you need to specify more, the question is unclear. try with giving some sample data, i.e: why when 6 books then 2 acc_no

Comment: I'm sorry had a lot of typos there corrected it now

Comment: This is a good example of the need for [database normalization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm). You want to separate your data elements into logical groupings linked by one-to-many relationship: distinct Call No table with Title and No. of Copies and multiple Acct No table (with foreign key - Call No.).

Comment: Show some sample data

Answer (score -1):

No. Use a multi-key index constraint and insert multiple records and format them as a single entry programmatically, or simply insert a json array into the column.